# K-Means plus plus implementation

Tags: python, colors, cluster-computing, k-means

My score was to get the most frequent color in a image, so I implemented a k-means algorithm.
The algorithm works good, but the result is not the one I was waiting for.
So now I'm trying to do some improvements, the first I thought was to implement k-means++, so I get a beter position for the inicial clusters centers.

First I select a random point, but how can I select the others. I mean how I define the minimal distance between them.

Any help for this? Thanks

Comment: You need to point out what is your input data. K-means is a clustering algorithm, not a frequency counter.

Comment: Of course, my imput data are image's pixels translated from RGB to Lab.

Comment: Since each pixel represents a different color, wouldn't the solution be simply to count the frequency of each color and pick the most frequent one? Or what you want is something other than "get the most frequent color in an image"?

Comment: I'm sorry it was the most 4 prodominant colors, so I implement k-means

Comment: @Rubens This works if the image contains many pixels with identical colours, but in practice, this is not the case.

Comment: @MichaelMior I just did not understand ice_mint's question, that's why I've asked and pointed out what I had understood. Applying k-means for simple frequency count sounded strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a vector quantisation.  You can make a list of each pixel and each adjacent pixel in x+1 and y+1 direction and pick the difference and plot it along a diagonale. Then you can calculate a voronoi diagram and get the mean color and compute a feature vector. It's a bit more effectice then to use a simple grid based mean color.

Comment: Is just to improve k-means?Or to change k-means for this one

Comment: Yes, to improve k-means.